# Arithmetic exception when running a query on SEDE

Tags: support, data-explorer

We are not able to run a query like the following in SEDE:

```
select avg(viewCount) from Posts
```

It is giving us an arithmetic exception which should ideally not be the case.

All we need to do is change the column datatype to double.

Comment: Are you talking about the Data Explorer?

Comment: how about: select avg(Cast(viewCount) as Float) from Posts

Comment: It's already been asked by the same OP and answered on Meta.SO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355679/stack-exchange-arithmetic-overflow-error

Comment: This is not in any way a bug. You can't expect to add up the views from every single question in the database and not exceed INT_MAX. *Your query* needs updated, not our database tables.

Comment: It is worth trying to have you fix my bugs @animuson ... ;)

Comment: *All we need to do is change the column datatype to double.* Looking at the  available [datatypes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql) there is no `double` so your proposed fix will not work.

Answer (score 6):

> All we need to do is change the column datatype to double.

No. You are not going to change the data type of a column to accommodate *any* function you can call on it. The view count is an integral number. Just keep it that way.

You've asked the [same question on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355679/stack-exchange-arithmetic-overflow-error) already, and the solution there is the best available option, and that is casting it yourself:

```
select avg(CAST(viewcount as float)) as average from posts
```

<sub>(Credits to [Makoto](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1079354/makoto), who proposed this solution)</sub>

Comment: cast to bigint will work as well and maybe preferable over a float.